# Python 3 - open() in binary mode won't create files with special characters in the file name

Tags: python-3.x

```
for file in os.listdir("Recordings/"):
    with open(file[:-4] + ".txt", 'wb') as outf:
```

open() does not create the .txt file when the file name includes special characters (accents, diacritics etc.) when I would like it to. How can I handle this? There are no exceptions thrown. It just silently fails.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Patrick Windows 10

Comment: Can you provide an example? Are you sure the file is not created in another directory, ie the working directory of the script? `listdir` does **not** return the full path, only the file name

Comment: @DeepSpace I'm 100% positive that the file is not created anywhere else. While the script can open and create the .txt file for file names such as Recording1-Bulgarian.xml, it will not create the .txt file for Recording156-Numèè.xml.

Comment: @rocker7035 Well, since I can not reproduce it on WIn 10 myself you'll have to put your code in a bit more context as we'll need a piece of code that reproduces the behavior.

Comment: `f = open('Recording156-Numèè.xml', 'wb')` is sufficient to create the file on my Windows 10 machine. Can you try that?

Comment: Python 3.4+ has a new standard library module [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) that aims to unify the various path operations you might want in a more OOP style. You might find it easier to reason about your code if you translated it to use that API instead of string manipulation and the various `os` module functions.

Answer (score 0):

It actually didn't fail. You just didn't notice that the file it created was under a different directory.

`os.listdir` returns only the filename portion of the paths. If you want to open the file under the same directory, you need to prepend the filenames with the directory name yourself with `os.path.join`.

```
for file in os.listdir("Recordings/"):
    with open(os.path.join("Recordings/", file[:-4] + ".txt"), 'wb') as outf:
```